# Is this sum converges or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\int_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\arctan\Big((-1)^nn^2\Big)}{n\ln^3n}$$

i will be glad if anyone can help me. I tried comparing it to the sum of $\Sigma_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{nlnn}$ and i said the integral of this sum from 1 to infinity doesn't converge (infinity - 'ln 0', when ln 0 isn't legal)

Comment: But $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac 1{n(\ln n)^p}$ converges when $p\gt 1$. So why the comparison to $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n\ln n}$? And while $\ln 0$ does not exist, n ranges from $2$ to $\infty$

Comment: we strongly encourage users to accept a helpful answer to each question asked (you can accept only one, but can upvote as many answers as you like). To accept an answer, just click  on the $\large \checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept: it turns green when you click on it, and you receive 2 reputation points each time you accept an answer.

Answer (score 3):

It converges absolutely since
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\biggl|\frac{\arctan((-1)^nn^2)}{n\ln^3n}\biggr|<\frac\pi2\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n\ln^3 n}<\infty
$$
using the fact that
$$
|\arctan x|<\frac\pi2
$$
for $x\in\mathbb R$.

We have that
$$
\sum_{n=2}^N\frac1{n\ln^3 n}=\frac1{2\ln^32}+\sum_{n=3}^N\frac1{n\ln^3 n}
$$
and, by [approximating the sum by a definite integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum#Approximation_by_definite_integrals),
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=3}^N\frac1{n\ln^3 n}\le\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_2^N\frac1{x\ln^3x}\mathrm dx=\lim_{N\to\infty}\biggl[-\frac1{2\ln^2x}\biggr]_2^N=\frac1{2\ln^22}.
$$
Hence,
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n\ln^3 n}<\infty.
$$

Comment: but how did you now $\frac\pi2\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n\ln^3 n}$ converges?

Comment: @Student_Afeka Use the [integral test for convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test).